# ActiveRecord group count with zeroes

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, grouping

```
Company.group('year(created_at)').group('month(created_at)').count
#=> {[2015, 4]=>62, [2015, 5]=>77, [2015, 6]=>61, [2015, 7]=>19, [2015, 8]=>16}
```

The above AR query returns grouped count of companies by year and month.

The issue is that it does not return any entry for group with **zero** companies.

I would expect the query to return all the groups, **containing every month starting from the month, when first company was created_at up to the current month**, like this:

```
{[2015, 4]=>62, [2015, 5]=>77, [2015, 6]=>61, 
 [2015, 7]=>19, [2015, 8]=>16, [2015, 9]=>0} #note the last entry - it is September (9nth month) with zero companies.
```

I know, that MySQL needs at least one row to return a group.

Are there (sure there are) workarounds for my need?

### EDIT

I am looking for a AR query solution without introducing any new tables or so.

Comment: yeah, I _hate_ long one-line snippets of code. When you scroll them, the scrollbar hides most of the code and it's impossible to read or see if you scrolled enough :)

Comment: Absolutely, I used to copy such long snippets to console or somewhere else to see the whole thing!

Comment: If you created a sample data set in sqlfiddle, I'd tinker with it :)

Comment: I didn't yet. Is there any chance you could look for solution based on any database of rails project of yours?

Comment: Have you thought about a [calendar table](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)? The site is pretty lame, but there are awesome usecases for such a table. Here's a [recent usecase](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30303194/2235594) of mine.

Comment: How does AR or MySQL know the upper/lower date range you want to create the groups for? You don't have any records in DB within the given month - but why stop at Sep? Why not Oct? etc... It looks like it has to be a Ruby solution merging the result with the full-range you want to create the groups for.

Comment: @tamersalama if you scroll like few inches you'd see that I already have a Ruby solution. Why not Oct? Because current month is September. What is the point of your comment? What did it bring to the table?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I've seen the Ruby solution - but it doesn't say you need groups up to current month (or starting from a particular date).

Comment: My bad, I'll edit the question!

Comment: I recently had to do exactly the same, I added a [use case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30303194/2235594) to easily create such a `CalendarDay` model... I'll expand my answer later

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about a [calendar table](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)? Although the site is very old, it still describes the use of such a table very well:

> - Generate a running sales total per day and include days in which you have no sales such as weekends.
> - Need to track data by seasons, whatever that means to your company.
> - Need to compare data using rolling months/periods.

---

> While many of these issues can be handled by writing SQL code, they’re much easier with a dedicated date table. Also, the Date Table can be customized to track anything about a particular day you want.

So in your case you would create such a table and then simply join it with your `Company` model.

Leading to a query like:

```
CalendarDay.where(year: Date.current.year).joins(:companies).group('YEAR(companies.created_at)').count
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I would prefer a solution without introducing new tables, if possible.

Comment: I can't think of another solution, but I'm eager for more answers