# grouping records with all the possible dates

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I need to get the number of records created in a specific period of time. What I'm trying to use right now looks kinda like this:

```
User.where('created_at between ? and ?', start, finish).group("date(created_at)").count
```

What i get is hash with dates as keys and numbers as values. BUT when a value is 0 for a specific day, it is not included in the hash. how can i include these dates as well? I mean MySQL, NOT Ruby language, i want it to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

AR or MySQL can not create the group if there are no records in DB within the given range.

I [had a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579189/activerecord-group-count-with-zeroes) and I only was able to solve it with Ruby..

```
User
  .where('created_at between ? and ?', start, finish)
  .group("date(created_at)")
  .flat_map{ |a,b| [a => b.count] }
  .inject(:merge)
```